# Character limit for static cards/buttons title in Lex

Tags: amazon-web-services, button, amazon-lex

I've been adding static cards and buttons to my Lex slots and noticed that often the cards/buttons do not display if the "Title" of the card goes beyond a certain character limit. It displays the buttons when I cut short the title.

Does anyone know what this limit is? I tried reading the documentation but couldn't find anything, the only other way to find out is by trial and error so any help is appreciated!

(Not talking about the button text itself which has a character display limit of 15)

Comment: If its not in the docs, that ` trial and error ` approach is good. Please let me know what you find. I also sometimes work with Lex, so it would be good to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this with the AWS Support team, they iterated the title length (trial-and-error) to find that **80 characters is the limit**, and confirmed it with the limit in their code as well.

Also feedback has been submitted to the docs team to include the info in the documentation!